# FIrestore Query Document in Collection Using Single Field/Attribute in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch the role of the currently authenticated user stored in `users collection`. What I am trying to achieve is at login time, query the user role by traversing fetching the user's document in the collection and sifting through the fields or checking all documents and returning the field `role` as a string.

Collection and document snapshot(excuse the terminology):
[image]

All documents in `users collection` have same fields for now.

Please how do I go about writing this type of query in flutter? I have tried using `AuthResult` in my service and `FirebaseAuth` to get current user(but no way to access the fields in the document).
Thanks.

```
String role;

getUserRoleWithFuture() async {
String currID = await _authService.getCurrentUID();
String mRole;
Firestore.instance.collection(USERS_REF).document(currID).get().then((doc) {
  mRole = doc.data['role'];
  print(mRole);
});
return mRole;
}

Future<String> getUserRoleWithStream() async {
String currID = await _authService.getCurrentUID();
String sRole;
Firestore.instance
    .collection(USERS_REF)
    .document(currID)
    .snapshots()
    .listen((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
  if (ds.exists) {
    sRole = ds.data['role'];
    print('with stream:\t$sRole');
  }
});
return sRole;
}
```

In the method `getUserRoleWithStream()` I am trying to retrieve the value printed out like `role = getUserRoleWithStream()` but instead get this in console `a value of type Future<String> can't be assigned to a variable of type string`.

How do I get this value using either the stream (cos it constantly observes the collection) or using the other method and use it in my widget?
Thanks again.

Comment: Show your current code, how you are doing?

Comment: Check again, haven't tried querying before

Answer (score 2):

This is the working solution, in case anyone else runs into this. I appreciate the effort made into helping me understand the issue but here's the answer:

```
String role;

getUserRoleWithFuture() async {
  String currID = await _authService.getCurrentUID();
  String mRole;
  Firestore.instance.collection(USERS_REF).document(currID).get().then((doc) {
    mRole = doc.data['role'];
    print(mRole);
   });
   return mRole;
 }

Future<String> getUserRoleWithStream() async {
  String currID = await _authService.getCurrentUID();
  String sRole;
  Firestore.instance
    .collection(USERS_REF)
    .document(currID)
    .snapshots()
    .listen((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
     if (ds.exists) {
       sRole = ds.data['role'];
       print('with stream:\t$sRole');
     }
   });
   return sRole;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, I assume the `AuthResult.user.uid` and your user's collection user's id is same. So that once you have the user from `AuthResult`, you can query your firestore collection to get the user's role as follows.

```
Future<String> getUserRole(String uid) async {
    DocumentSnapshot ds = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).get();
    return ds.data['role'];
  }
```

Comment: This is the error trace: Instance of 'Future<String>'
E/flutter (32759): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (32759): Receiver: null
E/flutter (32759): Tried calling: []("role")

Comment: Your code seems logically correct but for some reason is not working

Comment: As I said is the uid and document id same when user document is created in Firestore??

Comment: Yes, they are the same

Comment: Found a way to query the field using id, it works now but can't return the string I want